# EF 7 Commands Powershell Scripts need to be reinstalled on project load

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-core

At first I thought my EF 7 packages weren't being installed correctly via NuGet.  I then later realized that they were installed just fine, but the powershell scripts, specifically the (init.ps1 and install.ps1) that are brought down with the EntityFramework.Commands -Pre were only running during the intial NuGet installation.  Now every time I reload the project, I have to rerun both the init and install scripts in order to Add-Migration or take advantage of any other PS cmdlet.

Is this a bug? How can I fix this myself? I remember reading that if I create a powershell script named the same as my project it will automatically run it during project load.  Maybe I am way off, but do I need to create a script that loads these 2 also or am I missing something?

```
<package id="EntityFramework.Commands" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="EntityFramework.Core" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="EntityFramework.Relational" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="EntityFramework.Relational.Design" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Pretty much the same thing you get for the past 3 months doing an Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -Pre and or a EntityFramework.Commands -Pre.  I haven't seen the version change since using this.

Comment: That is not precise enough... share your packages.config or project.json, please

Comment: Updated...but the version hasn't changed since I started using EF 7.

Comment: It change on a daily basis, but not on Nuget.org - RC2 is coming "soon"

Comment: Any ideas about the powershell question?

Comment: What OS version and VS version?

Comment: Win 10, VS 2015 Update 2